# How can I find out that my redis channel does not currently have the publisher?

Tags: node.js, redis

How can I find out that my redis channel does not currently have the publisher?

Comment: Hello, can you please rewrite your question in English? Not everyone understands Russian.

Comment: Hello, i'm sorry for that. How can I find out that my redis channel does not currently have the publisher?

Comment: @KirillMescharikov there is no way to know that, whenever `publish mychannel mymessage ` is  executed you will have a `publisher`.

Comment: @Ersoy How then could I find out that my app / redis channel no longer has a publisher? For example, if one of the servers that was the publisher was down for any reason

Comment: let's say you create a new subscriber, it will only focus on whether there is a new message for that channel. this subscriber will alert you(email, slack message etc) whenever it doesn't receive a message in 5/10/60/720 minutes etc. Then you know there is a problem.

Comment: @Ersoy thank u so much. You have helped me a lot. If it doesn’t bother you, could you please explain to me how to avoid the “race condition” between subscribers correctly? That each message was processed only once by one subscriber

Comment: (I am not sure whether i get it right) there is no limit for number of subscribers in pubsub, so each consumer will receive the exact message while they are listening that channel. If you need only one listener to receive a single message, you may check `queues` - even there are 10 listeners - only 1 pull that message from the `queue`.

Comment: @Ersoy What do you mean by check queues? The fact is that for understanding, I ran two listeners on one channel and each of them received every message sent by the publisher

Comment: that's right. When you said "each message was processed only once by one subscriber " i thought you want only 1 process to consume a message even there are 10 subscribers. when i said "I am not sure whether i get it right" i was saying that.

Comment: @Ersoy oh, i'm sorry.I meant the fact that I would like to have an unlimited number of subscribers and that each of them could process messages. But in such a way that each message was processed only 1 time and only 1 subscriber. And I, unfortunately, do not quite understand what you mean by “queuing”, if it does not bother you, could you explain to me or set an example?

Comment: if there are 100 subscribers connected to a channel, when you publish a message - then 100 of them will receive 1 message. 1 message will be consumed by every subscriber connected to that channel. If you have 100 subscribers, want to publish 1 message and want only "one" of them(not 100) to process this message then you should use "queue" structure not pubsub. There are some info here https://medium.com/@weyoss/building-a-simple-message-queue-using-redis-server-and-node-js-964eda240a2a

Answer (score 0):

Redis `pub/sub` is fire and forget. once you publish the message no guarantee that it will deliver to the subscriber if subscriber not available at that time. Redis pub/sub will only guarantee that order of messages. I would suggest use Redis Stream. you can use consumer group in Redis stream to have multiple consumers. It will guarantee the message delivery with acknowledgement option. 
[Please go through](https://redis.io/topics/streams-intro)

Use **PUBSUB** **CHANNELS** [channelname] to find the number of subscribers for the specified channels/publisher.